# Работа с HashMap

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. 
У меня возникла такая проблема, может кто поможет с её решением.
Нужно с помощью `HashMap` дописать к тегам 2 атрибуты `a="1"` и `b="2"`, чтобы получилась xml такой структуры:

```
<to a = "1" b = "2">Tove</to>
```

У меня почему то получается только так:

```
<to b="2">Tove</to>
<to a="1">Tove</to>
```

Как сделать, чтобы 2 этих атрибута были в 1 строке а не в 2.

Вот как я делаю:

```
HashMap<String, String> attr = new HashMap();
public void addChild(String teg, String text) {
    String a = "1";
    String b = "2";
    String attributes;
    attr.put("a", a);
    attr.put("b", b);
    Set set = attr.entrySet();
    Iterator i = set.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
        attributes = (me.getKey() + "=\"" + me.getValue() + "\"");
        child = "<" + teg + " " + attributes + ">" + text + "</" + teg
                + ">\n";
        str.add(child);
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Можно было бы переделать но времени нет, код на завтра нужен. Хотелось бы доделать то, что есть.

Comment: И почему бы так получалось))

Ну вот у вас хардкодный маршалинг это плохо, не гибко.

Я бы рекомендовал использовать JAXB.

Можно, конечно дописать ваш код, но это вообще неправильно.

Answer (score 2):

Ну и напишите вот так:

```
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
    attributes = (me.getKey() + "=\"" + me.getValue() + "\"");
    me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
    attributes += (me.getKey() + "=\"" + me.getValue() + "\"");
    child = "<" + teg + " " + attributes + ">" + text + "</" + teg + ">\n";
    str.add(child);
}
```

Но я бы рекомендовал вам переделать.